# Need a loop of script part running by incrementing one parameter value

Tags: powershell, loops, increment, hpc

I have this part of a script where I am trying to launch a few analysis using our application API through Microsoft HPC to run different job types such as Job503, Job504 ....till Job513.

With only 2 Analysis servers to run the jobs, only 2 jobs can run at one time and up to 10 jobs can be in queue including the 2 running. So below Job503 is 2 jobs and up to Job507 is 10.

What I want to do is rather than writing a long script, I want to create an incrementing factor where in the first batch I can push job503 - job507, then script will wait until **$MetricValue -eq 0**(checked by the Ad-PSSnapin and while loop) then the script needs to push the next set of 10 jobs which job508 - job513. The value that we are incrementing is **DLMProfileID**, and also the -ObjectId parameter value needs to be 4 and 5 respectively for the set of 2 jobs as shown in the script.

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.HPC
 Set-Content Env:CCP_SCHEDULER $Clustername

 While ($MetricValue -ne 0)
    {
        Sleep -Seconds 60
        $MetricValue = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Clustername -ScriptBlock {
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.HPC;
        $Value = (Get-HPCMetricValue -Name "HPCJobsRunning" | where {$_.nodename -match "HN*" }).Value
        $Value
        }
        write-host $MetricValue
    }

#Job503
$retcn01 = Invoke-DlmApiDlmInitiateDLMAnalyse  { New-DlmAnalysisCommand -Edm "Test_EDM" -ObjectId 4 -DlmProfileId 503 }
Write-Output $retcn01
$retcn01 = Invoke-DlmApiDlmInitiateDLMAnalyse  { New-DlmAnalysisCommand -Edm "Test_EDM" -ObjectId 5 -DlmProfileId 503 }
Write-Output $retcn02

#Job504
$retcn01 = Invoke-DlmApiDlmInitiateDLMAnalyse  { New-DlmAnalysisCommand -Edm "Test_EDM" -ObjectId 4 -DlmProfileId 504 }
Write-Output $retcn01
$retcn01 = Invoke-DlmApiDlmInitiateDLMAnalyse  { New-DlmAnalysisCommand -Edm "Test_EDM" -ObjectId 5 -DlmProfileId 504 }
Write-Output $retcn02
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking and how it relates to the sample code. Please clarify by updating your question directly, ideally in the form of an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or as close as you can get to one.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.